# Cannot sign data using private key, getting algorithm not supported by the key in swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, iphone, cryptography

I have generated the private key in swift using the following code:

```swift
 let publicKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [
                kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag:"com.xeoscript.app.RsaFromScrach.public2".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject] // added this value
        let privateKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [
                kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag:"com.xeoscript.app.RsaFromScrach.private2".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject] // added this

        var keyPairAttr = [NSObject: NSObject]()
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeyType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 2048 as NSObject
        keyPairAttr[kSecPublicKeyAttrs] = publicKeyAttr as NSObject
        keyPairAttr[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs] = privateKeyAttr as NSObject

        statusCode = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)
```

And then I am using the private key to sign a piece of data, using the `SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaEncryptionPKCS1` algorithm.

The code to sign is as follows:

```swift
 public func sign(privateKey myPrivateKey: SecKey, value: String, base64EncodingOptions: Data.Base64EncodingOptions = []) throws -> String?
    {
        enum LoginErrors: Error {
            case badUsername
            case badPassword
        }
        guard #available(iOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, tvOS 10.0, *) else {
               return "Not available"
           }
        let data = value.data(using: .utf8)!

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let signedData = SecKeyCreateSignature(myPrivateKey,
                                                     SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaEncryptionPKCS1,
                                                     data as CFData,
                                                     &error) as Data? else
        {
            return nil
        }
        return "(signedData.base64EncodedString())"
    }
```

I am getting this exception:

```
[0] (null)  "NSDescription" : "algid:encrypt:RSA:PKCS1: algorithm not supported by the key <SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPrivateKey, version: 4, block size: 2048 bits, addr: 0x280a0e5a0>"
```

Comment: Can't test the code, but are you sure you don't mean to pass something like `SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256` into the createsignature call? Passing an encryption algorithm identifier .into a CreateSignature call seems odd.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson which part is failing for you? 
I can provide more code

Actually I am still figuring out the algorithm to use.

my java server stores the public key during registration and next time the device wants to communicate with server it sends the signed data with private key from device.

if I use `SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256` the verification fails at server side.

The java server use RSA, `SHA256withRSA` algorithm to verify.

Answer (score 1):

`SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaEncryptionPKCS1` is incorrect, this is attempting to use the RSA private key for hybrid encryption.

Instead pass something appropriate such as `rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256`, `rsaSignatureDigestPSSSHA256` or one of the other options shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckeyalgorithm).

*Note, `rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256` is deterministic.*

Additionally, I would suggest using elliptic curve signature, RSA in 2020, however tempting, is the wrong choice.

There are so many gorgeous libs that support ECC now I wouldn't be using SecKit.

Comment: I replaced rsaEncryptionPKCS1 with rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256, I am getting signed base64 string.

The real problem is cannot verify this using the public on java server.

Background: my java server stores the public key during registration and next time the device wants to communicate with server it sends the signed data with private key from device. if I use SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaSignatureDigestPKCS1v15SHA256 the verification fails at server side with boolean false on verify. The java server use RSA, SHA256withRSA algorithm to verify.

Comment: I am using this online tool to verify: https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?rsasignverifyfunctions=rsasignverifyfunctions&keysize=2048

Java code to verify:

  fun verify(publicKey: PublicKey, challenge: String, signature: String): Boolean {
        val sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
        sign.initVerify(publicKey)
        sign.update(challenge.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        return sign.verify(Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT))
    }

Comment: Sure I understand, personally I would just use libsodium both on iOS and Server side. Which lib are you using on the server? I reckon it's simply that the Server's RSA implementation is expecting a different padding scheme.

Comment: I am using `java.security.Signature` to verify.

Java code for verification:

 `fun verify(publicKey: PublicKey, challenge: String, signature: String): Boolean {
 val sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
        sign.initVerify(publicKey)
        sign.update(challenge.toByteArray())
        return sign.verify(Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT))
    }`

Comment: ah, this is nearly certainly incompatibility between padding schemes, I will look at this later as on mobile now.

Comment: sure I will wait for your analysis, and really appreciate you time. Thanks